# Sending a string from C# to insert into a PHP file to be immediately used in a mysql select query with the results returned

Tags: c#, php, mysql

So I have this php file with the following query

```
$query = "select Customer.CustID, LastName,FirstName,DOB,CustPhone, 
Max(TransDate) as LatestTransaction from Customer, History where 
Customer.AuthKey='A111' and Customer.AuthKey=History.AuthKey and 
Customer.CustID=History.CustID  Group by CustID;";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
  echo json_encode($rows);

  mysqli_close($con);
```

And then I do this C# here to get the results and put them into a datagridview

```
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var json = wc.DownloadString(URL);
            List<Customer> customers = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
            CustomerDataViewGrid.DataSource = customers;
```

There are no problems with this, however I would like to take

```
Customer.AuthKey = 'A111'
```

From the above select query in the php And instead pass the value from my C# code to it

```
$aKey = $_POST['Authkey'];
Customer.AuthKey = '$aKey'
```

I have tried to do this within the same button click event but I am not quite understanding how I can send this string and then immediately get the Downloading string.  When I hard code the Customer.Authkey it returns my results, but when I try to send this string it does not return anything.  How can I do this from the same event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection() {
    { "Authkey", "A111" },
};

byte[] result = wc.UploadValuesTask("<your_url_here>", "POST", formData);

string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
```

By this was you can send your auth key to your PHP script. The rest is up to you. Sorry if I misunderstood you, feel free to correct me.

Comment: I didn't have UploadValuesTask as an available method.  Could be the fact that I didn't specify I am using a lower framework.  But wc.UploadValues worked out fine.  Thanks.

Comment: You are right, I was using this part of the source code from my project where I called the function asynchronously. `wc.UploadValues` is the right method in this situation.